# R using lapply, sapply and vapply to get named list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I want to use a functional program to solve this problem

```
prob.designs= list()
prob.designs$UF1 = data.table(sigma = c(0, 0,01, 0.1, 1))
prob.designs$UF2 = data.table(sigma = c(0, 0,01, 0.1, 1))
...
prob.designs$UF10 = data.table(sigma = c(0, 0,01, 0.1, 1))
```

And I try the following code, which generates a list of dataframes but the lists' elements are not named UF1,UF2.....

```
prob.designs = lapply(paste("UF", 1:10, sep = ""), FUN = function(colname){
  prob.designs[[eval(colname)]]=data.table(sigma = c(0, 0.01, 0.1 ,1))}
)
```

The sapply works but in a wrong way since the names for the list becomes UF1.sigma rather than UF1

```
prob.designs = sapply(paste("UF", 1:10, sep = ""), FUN = function(colname){
  prob.designs[[eval(colname)]]=data.table(sigma = c(0, 0.01, 0.1 ,1))}
)
```

Finally, I tried vapply, but this is even more strange

```
prob.designs = vapply(paste("UF", 1:10, sep = ""), FUN = function(colname){
  prob.designs[[eval(colname)]]=data.table(sigma = c(0, 0.01, 0.1 ,1))}
  , FUN.VAL = data.table(sigma = c(0, 0.01, 0.1 ,1))
)
```

Now the names of the list are right, which is UF1, UF2,...UF10
but each element of the list now are not dataframes!

Could someone help me explain what happened to the three cases and most importantly, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: ? `sapply(paste0('UF', 1:10), function(x) data.frame(sigma = c(0, 0,01, 0.1, 1)), simplify = FALSE)`